# how to handle data from multiple checkboxes and multiple submits with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, button, checkbox

I am trying to post data from multiple checkboxes with several submit buttons.
Important is: the submit buttons are not part of the form because they are on a different place on the website.

This is what i have so far:

```
<form class="checkboxform" action="" method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="C/C++"><label>C/C++</label><br/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Java"><label>Java</label><br/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="PHP"><label>PHP</label><br/>
</form>
```

The submit buttons:

```
<button type="button" id="delete" name="delete" onclick="submitForm()" value="Delete"/>Delete</button>
<button type="button" id="move" name="move" onclick="submitForm()" value="Move"/>Move</button>
<button type="button" id="copy" name="copy" onclick="submitForm()" value="Copy"/>Copy</button>
```

The ajax:

```
function submitForm(url){
   var data = $(".checkboxform").serialize();
   $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url  : url,
    data: data,
    success :  function(data){
        $(".echo").html(data);
       }
   });
};
```

The php:

```
if($_POST['delete']) {
  if(isset($_POST['check_list'])){//to run PHP script on submit
    if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
        echo $selected."</br>";
        }
        // code for delete goes here
        echo 'Files are  deleted!';
    }
  }
}

if($_POST['move']) {
  if(isset($_POST['check_list'])){//to run PHP script on submit
    if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
        echo $selected."</br>";
        }
        //code for moving files goes here
        echo 'Files are moved!';
    }
  }
}

if($_POST['copy']) {
  if(isset($_POST['check_list'])){//to run PHP script on submit
    if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
        echo $selected."</br>";
        }
        // code for copy goes here
        echo 'Files are copied!';
    }
  }
}
```

By submitting, php does not handle the data. What i am doing wrong? Can someone help me with that?

All the code is in the same file, called `index.php`

Comment: Your buttons are not an input element inside your <form> element, so your if statements checking for their submitted names are never resolved.

Comment: ok. How can i achieve this to work when buttons are outside the form? Because the buttons are on a different place on the website

Answer (score 0):

Your js function has a parameter

```
function submitForm(url){
```

But when you call the function, there is no parameter set

```
 onclick="submitForm()"
```

As that parameter is the URL to send the POST to, it never gets there. You probably should be seeing some errors in the browsers developer window. F12 to open the developer windows.

As you are running the same PHP script regardless of whether it is a delete, move or copy. I would remove the parameter and hardcode the url in the function like this.

```
function submitForm(){
   var data = $(".checkboxform").serialize();
   $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'path/to/the.php',
    data: data,
    success :  function(data){
        $(".echo").html(data);
       }
   });
};
```

Comment: I made these changes but in the echo, he repeates  the form elements back. Not the php echo!

Comment: Does that script start with a `<?php` tag?

Comment: Actually forget that.... **All you do in that script is repeat the form element back to the Ajax call**. So thats what the PHP code is written to do !!!!! And it is doing that!

Comment: ok. But in that case,  how can i catch the values from the checkboxes and handle them in the php?

Comment: That sounds like a completely different question! But you have the values, you echo them. So in each IF you have to code something to DO whatever you want to do

Comment: So this line `// code for delete goes here` should be inside the IF and thats where you do the DELETE or MOVE or COPY of whatever it is you are deleteing or moving or copying

Comment: As the Dolphins said "...and thanks for all the fish"